# Query of result from dropdown menu

Tags: php, sql, dropdown

Need help for my last query. When I submit, I want to show all the columns of that particular LRN. I can't get it to work. When I click submit, it doesn't show anything. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'user, 'pwd') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select * from students");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<form method = POST>";
echo "<select name = 'Students' onchange=this.form.submit()>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($LRN, $First, $Last);
              $LRN = $row['LRN'];
              $First = $row['First_Name'];
              $Last = $row['Last_Name']; 
              echo '<option value="'.$LRN.'">'.$Last.', '.$First.'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Show'>";
echo "</form>";

$submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'submit');
$students = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Students');


if(isset($submit)) {
    $tae = $conn->query('select * from students WHERE LRN=.$Students.');
    echo $tae;
}
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: Think about the life cycle of a web form page!!!!

Comment: Your second query is not being constructed properly: `'select * from students WHERE LRN='.$students`

Comment: Also you do a sensible query and result processing in the first query, why then in the second do you think `echo $tae;` is going to do anything useful in the second

Comment: Plus what @Welbog said about the query. It looks like someone else wrote the rest of the code and you just picked up the last bit

Comment: no, I made that. I'm just newbie that's why.

Comment: btw, I'm writing this on a wordpress webpage with php code plugin.